# Generate thumbnail images with alpha channel from a video which has an alpha channel using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm working with ffmpeg and processing MOVs with alpha channels. I want to generate a sequence of images and preserve the alpha channel in the images generated.

Any guidance or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution on StackOverFlow.com: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742506/convert-flv-video-with-alpha-channel-to-pngs-with-transparency
`./ffmpeg -i ../videos/video.mov -r 25 -vcodec png -pix_fmt rgb32 %d.png`

Comment: I'm glad you found an answer on SO.  If you could include a link to the actual answer here, that would be helpful for anyone trying to find more information.